# Videocapture stuck when IP camera is disconnected

Tags: opencv, visual-c++

i am working with opencv 2.4.9  mvsc++2012 and Qt,   the code works perfectly when the camera is connected but if the camera gets disconnected the code stuck at vcap.open(videostreamadress) 
here is my code

```
const string videoStreamAddress="rtsp://admin:admin@192.168.1.11:88/live/h264/VGA";
VideoCapture  vcap;
Mat image_input;
cameraOpen=true;
//first open the graphic widget to display the camera stream
ui.graphicsView->setEnabled(TRUE);
    while ((vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)==true)&&(cameraOpen==true))
         {
            if(vcap.read(image_input)==false) 
                {
                //QmessageBox 
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setText("probleme de connexion a la caméra");
                msgBox.exec();
                //close_camera_feed();
                break;
                }           
                vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 1);
                //vcap.read(image_input);
                qimage_input = QImage((const unsigned char*)(image_input.data), 
                                        image_input.cols,image_input.rows, 
                                        QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
                image = QPixmap::fromImage(qimage_input);
                scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
                scene->addPixmap(image);
                scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
                ui.graphicsView->setScene(scene);
                //to 
                qApp->processEvents();
                 //thread t1(task1, "Hello");
                detect_license_plate(image_input);
            }

        if(vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)==false)
            {
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setText("La Caméra est déconnecté, vérifier l'uinstallation");
                msgBox.exec();  
            }
```

Thanks for your help in advanced!

Comment: Why are you initializing the camera on every iteration? Change two lines: `while ((vcap.isOpened())){}` and `if(vcap.isOpened()==false){}`.

Comment: i tried the vcap.isOpened() did not wok too, and for the if(vcap.isOpened()==false){} is to know the cause of the while loop exits (by the user (if(vcap.open(videoStreamAddress)==false)) or because the camera is offline .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the way i solved this problem is by using threads, i check the camera connection in a separate thread and wait for a period of time (2 seconds) if that thread do not finish and do not return any value it means that the camera is not connected.here is the code

```
cameraOpen=true; 
//first open the graphic widget to display the camera stream
ui.graphicsView->setEnabled(TRUE);
cameraIsConnected = false ;

while ((check_camera_thread()==true)&&(cameraOpen==true))   
    //while ((vcap.isOpened()==true)&&(cameraOpen==true))
         {
            if(vcap.read(image_input)==false) 
                {
                //QmessageBox 
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setText("probleme de connexion a la caméra");
                msgBox.exec();
                //close_camera_feed();
                break;
                }           
                vcap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FPS, 1);
                //vcap.read(image_input);
                qimage_input = QImage((const unsigned char*)(image_input.data), 
                                        image_input.cols,image_input.rows, 
                                        QImage::Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped();
                image = QPixmap::fromImage(qimage_input);
                scene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
                scene->addPixmap(image);
                scene->setSceneRect(image.rect());
                ui.graphicsView->setScene(scene);
                //to 
                qApp->processEvents();
                 //thread t1(task1, "Hello");
                detect_license_plate(image_input);
            }

        if(vcap.isOpened()==false)
            {
                QMessageBox msgBox;
                msgBox.setText("La Caméra est déconnecté, vérifier l'uinstallation");
                msgBox.exec();  
            }                       
vcap.release();
close_camera_feed();
 } 
bool check_camera_thread()
 {
   std::thread t0( check_camera);   
   Sleep(2000);
   t0.detach();
   return cameraIsConnected;
  }
bool check_camera()
{
  vcap.open(videoStreamAddress);
  cameraIsConnected= true ;
  return cameraIsConnected;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment, use the following template to access your camera.

```
cv::VideoCapture vcap("url");
if(!vcap.isOpened())
{
    std::cout<<"Camera could not be opened"<<std::endl;
    return -1;
}

cv::Mat frame;
bool ret;
while(true) {

    ret = vcap.read(frame);
    if(!ret)
    {
        std::cout<<"Empty frame returned"<<std::endl;
        break;
    }

    /* Process frame here*/


    /* Set loop terminating condition here*/

}

vcap.release();
```

Comment: thank you for your response, but the problem i am facing is that the code will stay at this point of code  if(!vcap.isOpened()) and wont advance further if the camera is disconnected, the problem is that the vcap.isopened() do not return false if the camera is disconnected or do not exist

Comment: @harounbest How can it be stuck? The function either returns `true` or `false`. If it returns `false` then the `if` statement is true and program exits. If it returns `true` then execution continues to `while` loop and the `read` function will return empty frame which will break the loop. In either case execution *will* terminate.

Comment: that is the problem i am facing,  when the camera is connected it works fine and  the vcap.isOpened() retuns "true", but when the camera is disconnected it stuck and do not return any thing

Comment: maybe a driver bug of your camera